# C# Sorting imported .XML elements on a listbox

Tags: c#, xml

I have created an xml file to store the user transaction history. when  a user want to show the transaction history I add them to a listbox , but the problem the order of the elements is not correct I want the last transaction made to be shown in the list firs. I have tried many way to sort them, but none of which worked for me. I think If I use the tcounter that I have to sort the elements it will work for example if the last item was added when the tcounter was 4 I want the item to be order like this:
4
3
2
1
20
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
My Method to add a transaction :

```
 public void addtransaction(string accounttype, int accountnumber, string    type, int ammount)
     {
        if (tcounter > 20)
        {
            tcounter = 0;
        }
        ++tcounter;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("USERS.xml");

        {
            if (id != 0)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
                {
                    if (id == int.Parse(node["ID"].InnerText))
                    {
                        node["tcounter"].InnerText = tcounter.ToString();
                        switch (tcounter)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                node["t1"].InnerText =   tcounter+"."+accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                node["t2"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");

                                break;
                            case 3:
                                node["t3"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                node["t4"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");

                                break;
                            case 5:
                                node["t5"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                node["t6"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");

                                break;
                            case 7:
                                node["t7"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + "." + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");
                                break;
                            case 8:
                                node["t8"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");

                                break;
                            case 9:
                                node["t9"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");
                                break;
                            case 10:
                                node["t10"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");

                                break;
                            case 11:
                                node["t11"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");
                                break;
                            case 12:
                                node["t12"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");

                                break;
                            case 13:
                                node["t13"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");
                                break;
                            case 14:
                                node["t14"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");

                                break;
                            case 15:
                                node["t15"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");
                                break;
                            case 16:
                                node["t16"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");

                                break;
                            case 17:
                                node["t17"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");
                                break;
                            case 18:
                                node["t18"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");

                                break;
                            case 19:
                                node["t19"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");
                                break;
                            case 20:
                                node["t20"].InnerText = tcounter + "." + accounttype + accountnumber + type + ammount + " " + time; doc.Save("USERS.xml");

                                break;

                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My Method to import the elements from the xml file to the listbox:

```
private void accounthistorybttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
XmlDocument doc11 = new XmlDocument();
        doc11.Load("USERS.xml");
        {
            if (id != 0)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode node in doc11.DocumentElement)
                {
                    if (id == int.Parse(node["ID"].InnerText))
                    {
                        item = node["t1"].InnerText;
                        item2 = node["t2"].InnerText;
                        item3 = node["t3"].InnerText;
                        item4 = node["t4"].InnerText;
                        item5 = node["t5"].InnerText;
                        item6 = node["t6"].InnerText;
                        item7 = node["t7"].InnerText;
                        item8 = node["t8"].InnerText;
                        item9 = node["t9"].InnerText;
                        item10 = node["t10"].InnerText;
                        item11 = node["t11"].InnerText;
                        item12 = node["t12"].InnerText;
                        item13 = node["t13"].InnerText;
                        item14 = node["t14"].InnerText;
                        item15 = node["t15"].InnerText;
                        item16 = node["t16"].InnerText;
                        item17 = node["t17"].InnerText;
                        item18 = node["t18"].InnerText;
                        item19 = node["t19"].InnerText;
                        item20 = node["t20"].InnerText;


                        List<string> ListaServizi = new List<string>() { item, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11, item12, item13, item14, item15, item16, item17, item18, item19, item20 };
                        ListaServizi.Sort();
                        historylistBox1.Items.Clear();
                        historylistBox1.DataSource = ListaServizi;
```

My XML file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
<User PIN ="5100">
 <ID>123456</ID>
 <tcounter>0</tcounter>
 <Name>Kamal Al Nasr</Name>
 <CheckingACCNum>52645852</CheckingACCNum>
 <CheckingACCBalance>2500</CheckingACCBalance>
 <SavingACCNum>741852</SavingACCNum>
 <SavingACCBalance>2000</SavingACCBalance>
 <Address>3500 John Merritt Blvd, Nashville, TN 37209</Address>
 <Phone>(615) 963-5848</Phone>

  <t1> </t1>
  <t2> </t2>
  <t3> </t3>
  <t4> </t4>
  <t5> </t5>
  <t6> </t6>
  <t7> </t7>
  <t8> </t8>
  <t9> </t9>
  <t10> </t10>
  <t11> </t11>
  <t12> </t12>
  <t13> </t13>
  <t14> </t14>
  <t15> </t15>
  <t16> </t16>
  <t17> </t17>
  <t18> </t18>
  <t19> </t19>
  <t20> </t20>

</User>
<User PIN ="5110">
  <tcounter>0</tcounter>
  <ID>123457</ID>
  <Name>Mike Stewart</Name>
  <CheckingACCNum>8569745</CheckingACCNum>
  <CheckingACCBalance>500</CheckingACCBalance>
  <SavingACCNum>741850</SavingACCNum>
  <SavingACCBalance>3000</SavingACCBalance>
  <Address>110 Nevada Ave., Nashville, TN 37219</Address>
  <Phone>(615) 963-5555</Phone>

<t1> </t1>
<t2> </t2>
<t3> </t3>
<t4> </t4>
<t5> </t5>
<t6> </t6>
<t7> </t7>
<t8> </t8>
<t9> </t9>
<t10> </t10>
<t11> </t11>
<t12> </t12>
<t13> </t13>
<t14> </t14>
<t15> </t15>
<t16> </t16>
<t17> </t17>
<t18> </t18>
<t19> </t19>
<t20> </t20>
</User>
<User PIN ="5111">
<ID>123450</ID>
<tcounter>0</tcounter>
<Name>Adam Lin</Name>
<CheckingACCNum>8565478</CheckingACCNum>
<CheckingACCBalance>4500</CheckingACCBalance>
<SavingACCNum>741844</SavingACCNum>
<SavingACCBalance>2000</SavingACCBalance>
<Address>1120 Virginia Ave., Nashville, TN 37210</Address>
<Phone>(615) 963-4444</Phone>

<t1> </t1>
<t2> </t2>
<t3> </t3>
<t4> </t4>
<t5> </t5>
<t6> </t6>
<t7> </t7>
<t8> </t8>
<t9> </t9>
<t10> </t10>
<t11> </t11>
<t12> </t12>
<t13> </t13>
<t14> </t14>
<t15> </t15>
<t16> </t16>
<t17> </t17>
<t18> </t18>
<t19> </t19>
<t20> </t20>
</User>
</root>
```

Comment: Is it always `t1 ... t20`? Now you sort ascending by the `InnerText` of the nodes. If you just want to reverse the order, the following is a quick method: just call `ListaServizi.Reverse();` after the sort.

Comment: Question aside, but using Array consists of 20 items instead of declaring 20 individual items will really save you from a lot of trouble.

Comment: your right calling      ListaServizi.Reverse();    will do the job but after the counter reches 20 the program start to add the element in a diffrent order which I do not know why.

Comment: I think If I use the tcounter that I have to sort the elements it will work for example if the last item was added when the tcounter was 4 I want the items to be order like this: 4 3 2 1 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 ,but how can I do it?

Comment: Try this :  ListaServizi.Sort((x,y) => int.Parse(x.Substring(1)).CompareTo(int.Parse(y.Substring(1) )));